# What all POST Rest API commands we can execute inside a azure container instance

Tags: azure, rest, azure-container-instances

I have build a docker linux image which includes azure cli, kubectl and terraform installation. I have pushed the image to azure container registry and created a container instance manually with that image. My container is running successfully and I am able to connect to it from the azure portal.

But my requirement is, I have to run some Rest API commands which is provided by the microsoft to perform certain action on the container. I have followed below microsoft documentation   for executing the rest api command.
Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/containers/execute-command#code-try-0

I just provided my container details and added body as below:

```
{
  "command": "/bin/bash",
  "terminalSize": {
    "rows": 12,
    "cols": 12
  }
}
```

I have received 200 response after running the above command. But when I tried running some different commands I am getting the 200 response but output is not changing. Can someone please share the information like what commands I can execute in azure container instance through the rest api.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this REST API is for the `exec` command that executes the bash command in the container. So it will create a socket session to communicate with the container, the returns are the socket session and the password.

And for the `exec` command, also for this REST API, it only can execute the single command, like `ls`, `/bin/bash`. But if you want to execute multiple commands like `ls -al` or `curl $url`, then it will fail. Actually, ACI does not support running multiple commands through the REST API or the `exec` command. The solution is you use the Azure CLI command `az container exec` to run the bash command `/bin/bash`, it will create a socket session for you, like an SSH connection. Then you can run commands inside the container. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But, I am trying to use UI it self to run a command but not getting the output response. I am using the below link and trying the POST execution step with Body as below:

{
  "command": "/bin/bash",
  "terminalSize": {
    "rows": 12,
    "cols": 12
  }
}  
I am getting response 200 after running above body request. But what type of commands I can run like from UI to get the output
I am following below link actually but in this microsoft link I don't find more commands.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/containers/execute-command

Comment: @LokeshM Do you read the answer carefully? The REST API just returns the socket to connect the container. The command I mean is the Azure CLI command [`az container exec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az_container_exec).

Comment: Thanks for the help charles. I tried executing couple of Linux based commands with az container exec but mostly getting error like below:
bash-5.0# az container exec --resource-group linux_test_container --nami-terraform-kubectl --exec-command "mkdir kubectl"
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"mkdir kubectl\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Comment: Just want to add one more requirement, actually if I want to run these az container exec commands then I need to connect to a virtual machine and connect to the container. But in my current scenario, we are planning to implement this solution in programmatical way. Is there any ways to implement this scenario in programmatic.

Comment: @LokeshM The only way is to create the scripts inside the image, and then use the command to run the script in the Dockerfile. This is no other way. Or you can move to other services like AKS.

Comment: @LokeshM Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?